# Using The Result From An If Statement To Execute A Switch Cases?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm not sure if this will work. I'm assuming it should , I just can't figure out how.

I am trying to execute a Switch case from the result from an If Statement.
For example if the result from the If is 1 , the first case executes

This is what I'm thinking:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"\tDetermine what has been inputted"<<endl<<endl;
    char value,ch;
    int option;

    do{

        cout<<"Input something: ";
        value = islower(value);
        cin>>value;
        if(value>='0' && value<='0'){
            option == 1;
        }
        else if (value=='a' || value=='e' || value=='i' ||value=='o' || 
value=='u') {
            option ==2;
        }

    switch(option){
            case 1:
                cout<<"You entered "<<value <<" a digit."<<endl;

                cout<<"Do you wish to test again? (Y/N): "<<endl;

                cout<<"Do you wish to test again? (Y/N): "<<endl;
                cin>>ch;
                break;
        case 2:
               cout<<"You have entered"<<value<<" a vowel"<<endl;

               cout<<"Do you wish to test again? (Y/N): "<<endl;
               cin>>ch;
               break;
       default:
             cout<<"That input is not valid"<<endl;
      }


   } while (ch == 'y' || ch =='Y');


    return 0;
}
```

Is what I'm thinking possible?

Comment: What happened when you tried it out?

Comment: why do you need a switch case for that? you can even put it inside the if statement.

Comment: Possible, but pointless - why not put the output statement in the if?

Comment: Fyi, `opt` is *indeterminate* if you input a value *not* in your test range. You never initialized it.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile...

Comment: Don't use magic numbers `48` and `57`. Use constants `'0'` and `'9'` -- or better yet, use the `isdigit` function. And if you want us to take the time to look at your code, please take the time to make sure it compiles and copy-and-paste your *exact* code into the question. Your code should work fine with a couple of fixes. `opt` has to be initialized to some value before you refer to it; in your code it's either `1` or indeterminate. Fixing the syntax error should be easy. I'll assume that this is a simplified example of something where a `switch` would actually make sense.

Comment: If i run it , I can enter a value but it terminates soon after. I'm sorry, i thought it would be easier that way .I'll replace with the entire code in the question

Comment: @Dante try to put a `std::cin.getline()` (OS Independent) or a `system("pause");` (Windows only I think) if your console closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intialize variables to avoid UB:

```
char value,ch = 0;
int option = 0;
```

this is true only if `value` is '0':

```
if(value>='0' && value<='0')
```

you have two typos: `==` instead of `=`

```
option = 1;
```

and

```
option = 2;
```

You might want to set `ch` to 'Y' in case of invalid output?

```
   default:
         cout<<"That input is not valid"<<endl;
```